# How to change default row height of a migrated Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

The old Google Spreadsheet has a default row height of 17. The new Google Sheets has a default row height of 21.

After a spreadsheet is [auto-migrated by Google](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922151145/https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6082736) to the new Google Sheets, the original row heights are maintained. That's fine.

However, when I create a new worksheet in the migrated sheet, the rows also have a row height of 17, whereas when I create a fresh Google sheet the default row height is 21.

The problem is that layouting in new Google Sheets differ based on the fact whether they were created from scratch or from a migrated old Spreadsheet.

**How can I change the default height of rows of a migrated Google sheet from 17 to 21?**

I guess my only option is to create a new spreadsheet from scratch and copy each worksheet individually.

Related:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/h7sdSRhRqas

Comment: Would a script be helpful, because there's no way to reset the default height.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to change the default row height. One workaround is to use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) to change the row height. You could use on change installable trigger to call the script every time a new sheet or row is added.

> Note:
>   If the cell includes breaklines, or it's wrapping setting is set to wrap it's not possible to adjust the row height to a height less than the required to by its content. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765452

Comment: See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765452

Answer (score 0):

**Change All Row Heights in a Google Sheet at once.**

This is my solution:

• Create a new Column in a sheet, put it at the end.

• Write some text in a cell i.e. xx
• Copy that cell

• Mark the column
• Then "Paste Special" (Paste values only) so that all cells in that column show "xx"

• Keep the column marked and choose a larger fontsize for that column (if you want to increase the row height)

Then all rows in the sheet will adapt to the row height in the new column.

Comment: What does "Mark the column" mean here?